# How can you make a public folder in Exchange system manager

Tags: exchange, outlook-2003

I have exchange 2003 and wondering how do i create a public folder in the exchange system manager?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ESM expand the Administrative Group, expand Folders, right click Public Folders and select New... Public Folder.

You can also create new PF's from Outlook if you have the proper permissions.